# Can independence feature be lost while conditioning on other variables?

Tags: independence

Assume $\theta_{i} \sim i.i.d. Bernoulli(p)$ and $S(\theta_{i})$ is a continuous function.

Can we say that, $\theta_{i}|S(\theta_{i}) \leq \gamma$ is also $i.i.d. Bernoulli(p)$. Here, $\gamma$ is some fixed value.

In other words, can conditioning impair the independence feature?

Comment: If you're conditioning $\theta_i$ on information that only depends on $\theta_i$, the family remains independent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you prove it somehow or elaborate on it?